# How to protect a single php page with htaccess?

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to restrict a PHP page in a website. This page is in a CMS.

The page is like this.

http://bioenergysciences.com/innerpage.php?id=1

For this I have updated my .htaccess file like this.

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /home/bioenerg/password/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
<Files http://bioenergysciences.com/innerpage.php?id=1>
   require valid-user
</Files>
```

Then I created `.htpasswd` file in a folder called "password". Because this is not secure if we created this in the root folder.

Then I added the generated password to this file. 
My .htpasswd file is like this.

```
bioenergysciences:NnrhAhZ/Nc912
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should name the file name in `<Files>`. Alternatively you can use [`<Location>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location).

```
AuthName "Restricted Area" 
AuthType Basic 
AuthUserFile /home/bioenerg/password/.htpasswd 
AuthGroupFile /dev/null 
<Files "innerpage.php">
   require valid-user
</Files>
```

---

Note that this won't check the query string. Matching a URL with query string is useless, because I could simply go to http://bioenergysciences.com/innerpage.php?foo=bar&id=1, which doesn't match the mentioned location and circumvent the protection.

If you don't want to protect the whole `innerpage.php` but only `id=1`, than implement [basic authentication in php](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php).

```
$authenticated = isset($_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'])
 && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] === 'bioenergysciences'
 && $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW'] === 'mypassword';

if ($_GET['id'] === 1 && !$authenticated) {
    header('WWW-Authenticate: Basic realm="My Realm"');
    header('HTTP/1.0 401 Unauthorized');
    echo 'Text to send if user hits Cancel button';
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jasny. I did it. But then it displays an error ERROR 500 - INTERNAL SERVER ERROR. And I cannot access the whole site.

Comment: Please get the error from error log and post it here.

Comment: When I add the above code you gave me, I can't access the all inner pages. Is there a way to restrict a page with specific ID?

Comment: [17-Jun-2015 04:37:19 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  include(includes/contact_header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/bioenerg/public_html/email-submit.php on line 9

[17-Jun-2015 04:37:19 America/Chicago] PHP Warning:  include(includes/contact_header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/bioenerg/public_html/email-submit.php on line 9

Comment: @OreliyaFernando Those are PHP warnings and don't have to do with the `<files>`.

Comment: Thank you very much Jasny. I was able to fix my issue. It was really helpful. :)